# How to pass json filters to mvc grid without form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, mvcgrid

I am using ajaxify for refreshing mvc grid.

```
 $("[data-gridname='testGrid']").gridmvc();
             pageGrids['accountAjaxGrid'].ajaxify(
             {
                 getPagedData: $('#pagingActionUrl').val(),
                 getData: $('#pagingActionUrl').val(),
                 gridFilterForm: $("#gridFilters")
             });
```

Here '#gridFilters' is a form.
But i want to send a json instead of form.